# How to select at least 3 checkboxes through loop in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to allow at least 3 checkbox will check, I have tried below code but it's not works well.

HTML ...

```
<div class="ywapo_options_container">
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var parent =jQuery(document).find('#yith_wapo_groups_container').find('.ywapo_options_container');
        
        jQuery(parent).children().each(function(){
            if (jQuery(parent).children().length <=2 ) {
                //console.log("plaeae select at lest 3")
             }
        }); 
         
    });
```

Someone please help me , how can I select at least 2 checkboxes?

Comment: Do you want to do this before the form is submitted?

Comment: No, I don't do this before submitting

Comment: Instead of `.find().find()` in the document then `.children()`, why not simply `$(".ywapo_input_container_checkbox")` ?

Comment: @JeremyThille, I have taken find () 2 times because HTML code is large an I have not put whole my HTML code here. I just put require HTML code here

Comment: But the size of HTML is irrelevant. You can simply select all your checkboxes with one single selector (see our answers below)

Comment: Btw, what is `placeholder` supposed to achieve on `input type="checkbox"`?

Answer (score 0):

To determine how many of your checkboxes are checked simply get the length of the `:checked` instances (I checked one of the below just so you can see something other than zero)

```js
console.log($('.ywapo_input_checkbox:checked').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ywapo_options_container">
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed" checked>
    </div>
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want this to run every time one of the checkboxes is checked/unchecked you need an event handler

```js
$('.ywapo_options_container').on("change",".ywapo_input_checkbox", function(){
    console.log($('.ywapo_input_checkbox:checked').length);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ywapo_options_container">
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed" checked>
    </div>
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have selected 3 but still showing 1 in your code

Comment: Thats why I asked when you wanted to run this check. If you want to run it every time the state changes you need to add an event handler. Let me update the code.

Comment: Yes, you have to add some logic, like "On click, count the checkboxes again". But it works

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of checked checkboxes, you can simply do

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ywapo_options_container').on("change",".ywapo_input_checkbox", function(){
    console.log($('.ywapo_input_checkbox:checked').length);
})

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ywapo_options_container">
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
    <div class="ywapo_input_container ywapo_input_container_checkbox">
        <input  placeholder="" data-typeid="48" data-price="0" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" type="checkbox" name="ywapo_checkbox_48[0]" value="ywapo_value_48" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_checkbox ywapo_price_fixed">
    </div>
</div>
```